# Power calculation for case-control study

Tags: estimation, sample-size, case-control-study

My study is assessing whether there is a correlation between two medical conditions (endometriosis) and bleeding disorders.

The case participants have endometriosis and the controls do not.

In both case and control we are measuring a number of different haemostatic variables (clotting factor levels, platelet number, platelet function) which are continuous numerical values usually from between 0-150. We are measuring roughly 8 different variables.

I want to be able to demonstrate a signifant difference in the mean and range between cases and controls.

Do you know, roughly what the sample size estimation would be?

Many thanks,
Joanna

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! But no. A haematologist might because he'd have an idea of the variability in these measurements, & what size differences are considered important. Look up [power analysis](http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statsampsize.html) to see how to approach this, & then details of the calculations are easy to find for common models.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?